# String To C char** Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to call a C function in swift

```
int getValueFromC(char ** aValue);
```

In swift I see the "Type" is

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>
```

So i would call the function i swift using:

```
getValueFrom(myStringPointerPointer)
```

where myStringPointerPointer value would be at least initialised

Comment: Thank But that does not answer my problem.

Comment: Do you want to pass Swift strings to the C function, or get strings back from the C function?

Comment: A swift variable that will "End up" used as String because the c function will override it.

Comment: Note that you must take care of who is responsible for allocating and releasing the string storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var aVar:UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>? = nil
let aIntVar = getValueFromC(&aVar)
```